# SSRS toggle visibility for entire row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

In a drill down report, I have to hide an entire row starting from Jan 2017... then have to display it when I click the '+' symbol on the left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd5PD.png)

Some one please help me in solving the scenario in ssrs drilldown report

Comment: It is hard to give an answer when there is not question.

Comment: In Excel, you can hide an entire row by clicking on a "+" on the left, in a report, you can hide the details of a group, but at least the group header or footer that contains the toggle button will remain visible. This is, because in a report, these toggle buttons can't be "outside" the table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The "Add Matrix" wizard will do most, if not all of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have Column1 and Column2 in a tablix. Your Column1 is grouped by month (Jan, Feb, ...). In Column2 you have the Values. If you want to hide the Values from the entire row right click on the Column2 detail textbox then under **textbox properties -> Visibility - > Display can be toggled by this report item**. Check this option and chose in the drop down menue the dataset field with your months (this field is displayed in Column1). Now you can toogle at Column1 with the **+**